# Identify different executions (executing objects) of method?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have some (static) Java methods.

I have a pointcut to fire on the execution of any of these methods:

```java
pointcut calculation() : execution(* myMethod_*(..));
```

Now I want to measure the time of each execution seperately.
The problem is that executions may fire at any time, while other executions still run.
I thought about two advices, `before()` and `after()`, which identify the caller to manage timers for different callers.

```
before() : calculation() {

}

after() : calculation() {

}
```

How do I implement that?

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: Ok I have to accept the other answer because it matches the main aspect of the question, but thanks for your addition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

around() advice should work:

```
   Object around() : calculation() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Object result = proceed();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        logger.info(String.format("%s took %d ns", thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature(),
                (end - start)));
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This works fine!
With Thread.currentThread() I can figure out the executing thread, but can I also get the executing object?

Comment: Yes, you can collect the executing object with a `this` pointcut - `pointcut calculation(Object thisObject) : execution(* myMethod_*(..)) && this(thisObject);` then declaring around() this way: `Object around(Object thisObject):calculation(thisObject){...}`

Comment: There is a problem:
"advice [...] has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch] line [@ around] Java Problem" -
It seems that the pointcut doesn´t match anymore with the Java methods...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on Biju's answer, so I am creating a new one:

You asked:

> There is a problem: "advice [...] has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]" - It seems that the pointcut doesn't match anymore with the Java methods

Well, how should it match? Upon execution of your **static** methods (you mentioned that yourself) there is no `this` object, so the pointcut should be `call()` rather than `execution()`. Here is a complete code sample I created for you to demonstrate it:

Application class:

```
package de.scrum_master.aspectj.sample;

import java.util.Random;

public class Dummy {
    static Random random = new Random();

    static void myMethod_one() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
    }

    static String myMethod_two(int dummy) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
        return "dummy";
    }

    static int myMethod_three(double foo, String... dummy) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // We have no "this" here (static method), so advice is not applied
        myMethod_two(5);
        myMethod_one();
        myMethod_three(7.7, "foo", "bar");

        // Now let's create an object, so we have "this"
        new Dummy().doStuff();
    }

    void doStuff() throws InterruptedException {
        // Here advice is applied because we have "this"
        myMethod_one();
        myMethod_two(5);
        myMethod_one();
        myMethod_three(7.7, "foo", "bar");
        myMethod_three(3.3, "zot", "baz");
        myMethod_two(11);
    }
}
```

Timing aspect:

```
package de.scrum_master.aspectj.sample;

aspect TimingAspect {
    pointcut calculation(Object thisObject) :
        call(* myMethod_*(..)) && this(thisObject);

    Object around(Object thisObject) : calculation(thisObject) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Object result = proceed(thisObject);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(String.format(
            "%s (this = %s) took %d ns",
            thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature(),
            thisObject,
            end - start
        ));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to wrap each method with an object that has a start clock and an end clock. You can use:

```
System.nanoTime();
```

to save the start and end time. Thus your before and after calls can set the start and end time values. Or you can wrap those into a run command which sets start, runs the method, and then sets end.

By wrapping the method in an object you can abstract the timing controls to that object and do as many in parallel as you like -- each responsible for timing their own method.

Comment: Maybe you should give the code how to do the *wrapping* instead of how to get the system time. I tend to prefer the `around()` solution, but this sounds interesting too. The problem is that it doesn´t fall into place what you mean.